# How to convert a PowerShell array to avoid OverloadDefinitions

Tags: arrays, powershell

[Test-OnlineFast](http://community.idera.com/powershell/powertips/b/tips/posts/creating-highspeed-ping-part-5?CommentId=d1585b15-cd68-42e5-bd2c-1f1fe693e3aa) is a (great) custom function which creates an array with the following output incredibly quickly:

[image]

I can use this output on its own, but if I want to list just the addresses using the commands:

```
$Pinged = Test-OnlineFast $MyIPList.ipaddress    
$Pinged.Address
```

I receive the output:

[image]

Even though the array is a standard type:
[image]

This prevents me from doing things like comparing the array to another and matching the addresses.

Is there any way to 'convert' the array, so I can use it in this way? I've tried exporting it to a CSV or text file, and importing, but it's the same.

Comment: Could you edit the question and add more details? A sample that demonstrates the situation would be nice. This looks like an issue with object's ToString() method, but it's just a guess.

Comment: PowerShell displays the overloads of a *method* when you're calling a method without parentheses. What is the type of `$Array[0].GetType()`?

Comment: Looks like an array of `[IPAddress]` objects has a method `Address()` that expects a single integer parameter. I have no idea what purpose that method has, though.

Comment: I kept the question intentionally vague, as I didn't want to get bogged down answering a particular question, leaving no room for a general answer. The marked answer works fantasically.

Comment: @AnsgarWiechers `Address(int )` method belongs to array. It's array indexer (e.g. see `[int[]].GetMethod('Address') | ft`). It somewhat special since it returns `T&` -- managed pointer (`ref return` feature available since C# 7, but present in CLR since begging)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You could convert the array to a `List<psobject>`:

```
$list = [System.Linq.Enumerable]::ToList([psobject[]]$Array)
```

Since `List<psobject>` doesn't have a property called `Address`, you can now rely on property enumeration:

```
$list.Address
```

Answer (score 0):

`Address` method is actually the name of array indexer in CLR (see it return reference to array element type).

dot syntax (`$Pinged.Address`) is actually shorthand for

```
$Pinged | ForEach-Object { $_.Address }
# or more concisely
$Pinged |% Address
```